Remove WooCommerce Shop link from AIOSEO breadcrumbs
I am trying to remove the (woo commerce)SHOP link from AIOSEO breadcrumbs. I have custom category pages so it is vital to remove the link. I can find filters for YOAST and Woo Commerce but am unable to find help with AIOSEO breadcrumbs.
I added this filter to function.php, but it had no effect.
add_filter( 'aioseo_breadcrumbs_trail', 'aioseo_breadcrumbs_trail' );
function aioseo_breadcrumbs_trail( $crumbs ) {
    foreach ( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ) {
        if ( is_a( $crumb['reference'], 'WP_Term' ) && 'Shop' === $crumb['reference']->slug ) {
            unset( $crumbs[ $key ] );
        }
    }
    return $crumbs;
}


"but it had no effect" - have you tried some basic debugging then at least? Like a die("I'm in aioseo_breadcrumbs_trail now!"); at the start of the callback function, to verify whether it gets invoked at all? And if so, a var_dump of $crumbs, to see what it actually contains at this point?

FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Here is my opinion:
add_filter( 'aioseo_breadcrumbs', 'remove_shop_from_breadcrumbs' );

function remove_shop_from_breadcrumbs( $crumbs ) {
    foreach ( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ) {
        if ( isset( $crumb['reference'] ) && is_a( $crumb['reference'], 'WP_Term' ) && 'shop' === $crumb['reference']->slug ) {
            unset( $crumbs[ $key ] );
        }
    }

    // Reindex array to prevent issues with missing keys
    return array_values( $crumbs );
}

Thank you!
